# Docker-compose / init.sql doesn't get executed correctly

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to setup a local MySQL instance through `docker-compose`, which it looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  database:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    command: '--init-file /data/application/init.sql'
    command: 'mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    volumes:
      - './init.sql:/data/application/init.sql'
      - './data:/var/lib/mysql'
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    expose:
      - '3306'
    # cap_add:
    #   - SYS_NICE
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSW="${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
      - MYSQL_DATABASE="${MYSQL_DATABASE}"
      - MYSQL_USER="${MYSQL_USER}"
      - MYSQL_ROOT_USER="${MYSQL_ROOT_USER}"
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD="${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
    # network_mode: host
```

With the following **init.sql** script, that should take care of creating the db and setting the table up:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test;
USE test;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `listings`(
    id INTEGER
    ,PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The container gets built and starts normally:

```
Attaching to so-feed-parse_database_1
database_1  | 2019-12-12 14:58:39+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.18-1debian9 started.
database_1  | 2019-12-12 14:58:39+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
database_1  | 2019-12-12 14:58:39+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.18-1debian9 started.
database_1  | 2019-12-12 14:58:39+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
database_1  | 2019-12-12T14:58:39.976524Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
database_1  | 2019-12-12T14:58:39.976669Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.18) initializing of server in progress as process 46
database_1  | 2019-12-12T14:58:41.624212Z 5 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
database_1  | 2019-12-12 14:58:44+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized
database_1  | 2019-12-12 14:58:44+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
database_1  | 2019-12-12T14:58:44.542746Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
database_1  | 2019-12-12T14:58:44.542845Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.18) starting as process 95
database_1  | 2019-12-12T14:58:45.012478Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
database_1  | 2019-12-12T14:58:45.016362Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
database_1  | 2019-12-12T14:58:45.054899Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.18'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
database_1  | 2019-12-12 14:58:45+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
database_1  | 2019-12-12T14:58:45.128416Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock'
database_1  | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
database_1  | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
database_1  | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
database_1  | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
database_1  | 2019-12-12 14:58:47+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating database "test"
database_1  | 2019-12-12 14:58:47+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating user "utest"
database_1  | 2019-12-12 14:58:47+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Giving user "utest" access to schema "test"
database_1  | 
database_1  | 2019-12-12 14:58:47+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Stopping temporary server
database_1  | 2019-12-12T14:58:47.355373Z 14 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user root. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.18).
database_1  | 2019-12-12T14:58:49.162768Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.18)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
database_1  | 2019-12-12 14:58:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server stopped
database_1  | 
database_1  | 2019-12-12 14:58:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.
database_1  | 
database_1  | 2019-12-12T14:58:49.662509Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
database_1  | 2019-12-12T14:58:49.662675Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.18) starting as process 1
database_1  | 2019-12-12T14:58:50.034163Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
database_1  | 2019-12-12T14:58:50.036925Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
database_1  | 2019-12-12T14:58:50.062397Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.18'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
database_1  | 2019-12-12T14:58:50.222174Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
```

Now, after logging into the server, `show databases;` gives the following output (trying `use test;` outputs `unknown database`:

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| "test"             |
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Executing manually the init script works like a charm, no idea if it could be something depending on the `--init-file` command.

---

**Edit:**
The OP in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249276/docker-compose-mysql-init-sql-is-not-executed) question is following a similar approach without using `command: '--init-file'` but rather mounting the init.sql file on `./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql`.
After reshuffling my docker-compose.yml around the db is now created correctly. I am not quite sure why this is happening though...

Comment: Did you intentionally use more than one `command` line?

Comment: Yes, I had to switch the default auth plugin as without that command I was having protocol conflicts.

Comment: ....and what would happen if you combine both lines into a single one? I don't think that multiple `command`s are supported

Comment: Doesn't really help, apparently I was misusing `--init-file`. For MySQL init it should always be mounted and executed on the very first run. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48808069/how-to-create-database-in-database-docker-container) more on the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'./init.sql:/data/application/init.sql'` is not correct path, it should be mapped with `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`, as the entrypoint looking for files under `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`.

Also better to see this warning from the documentation.

**Warning:**

> scripts in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` are only run if you
>   start the container with a data directory that is empty; any
>   **pre-existing database will be left untouched on container startup**. One
>   common problem is that if one of your `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`
>   scripts fails (which will cause the entrypoint script to exit) and
>   your orchestrator restarts the container with the already initialized
>   data directory, it will not continue on with your scripts.

[postgres Initialization scripts](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres)

Comment: why do you talk about Postgres when the problem is connected to the mysql? I am having the same issue and unable to apply this solution by placing my init.sql to `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` (which does exist if it matters)

Answer (score 2):

Refer here https://onexlab-io.medium.com/docker-compose-mysql-initdb-4c3388047dea

[image]

Note：
mysql5.7 MYSQL_SERVICE_USER
If set  MYSQL_SERVICE_USER to `user`, then startup will not be executed

Comment: It's been a while since I last worked on this. Think one of the problems I was having might be related to the comment in your note. Thanks for yoru time, upvoting this.

Answer (score 0):

'--init-file /data/application/init.sql' may make an error. You should replace it with '--init-file=/data/application/init.sql'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).